# Appengine uploads are limited to 10000 files

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Attempts to deploy my application to appengine have failed because of the hard limit on uploads i.e. 10,000.

My application is using external libraries and constants in 2 other languages. Please refer to the following snapshot:

[image]

GWT.Async blocks have been placed in necessary positions in the project.

Following compile time options are used:
-localWorkers 3 -XfragmentCount 10

But the problem is when I upload the project to appengine I get the following exception:

**

> java.io.IOException: Applications are limited to 10000 files, you have
>   34731

**

I am aware that I can cut down on the file count by reducing the cross browser compatibility or by reducing locales. But that won't be a practical approach while deploying

So please suggest me some alternatives.

Another thing I wish to mention is the project extensively uses VerticalPanel/HorizontalPanel/FlexTable/DialogBox in most of its screens. I am not sure if this has something to do with this problem.

Comment: As John asked in Google+, how many split points do you have? How many permutations? If you had 100 split points and 100 permutations, that would result in just over 10,000 js/html files (plus various images, but those are much less likely to be duplicated so many times).

Comment: My last question is answered in part by the module file - 5 browsers, and three (or four including default) locales, but that doesn't include your own other modules that we can't see screenshots for.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I have 5 browser configs and three different languages(including english). I tried keeping one browser and no custom locale and it took 20 permutations. So in all I would require 100 permutations with no custom locale. But with 2 additional regional locales this would rise upto 300. That means to keep the file count under 10K I should not have more than 30-32 Split points. Here I am counting every GWT.Async block as one. Is this assumption correct??

Comment: I know you can't list all of the files, but can you do some quick analysis of them? How many <hash>.cache.html files are there (permutations), how many <N>.cache.js files, and what is the biggest N (i.e. how many split points). 20 perms + (20 perms * 30 split points = 600) still is less than 10% of the number you are seeing - I'm guessing the answer about too many class files is likely to be the real issue...

Comment: Thanks Colin. But classes generated in my case are <1K. So jarring them won't do much good here. I earlier had around 60 splits. I know quite large :). Now I have reduced these to 30 Splits and thus have managed to keep the generated files count <10K. Also I have observed that the temporary folder created by appcfg during upload, created dual copy of deferredjs folders(one being in _STATIC_ folder). I modified the appengine xml to ignore cache files in resource files by adding "<resource-files><exclude path="**.cache.*"/></resource-files>". Seems that I have contained the problem for now.

Comment: Just ran into this. I made an update to my app and suddenly I have 10073 files. Please Google, I am a paying customer, set this to infinite or at least 100000???

Comment: BTW push to deploy does NOT fail gracefully. Trying to deploy from git with 10000+ files, it just fails out after awhile with nothing but a cryptic error. In the end it says "Unable to get deployment status."

Comment: I would recommend moving as much content as possible the a storage service like Cloud Storage.  You can also separate this application into different modules/services and route using different subdomains or dispatch rules.  This effectively nets you significant file count allowances.  Lastly, this isn't really a technical question appropriate to Stack Overflow.  Best practice-type discussions are better suited to the [App Engine Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine).

Comment: If you'd like to have this hard cap of 10,000 files raised for the platform, I recommend filing a feature request on our [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) with the **Public Trackers > Cloud Platform > Compute > App Engine** component.  We also monitor that forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this will happen to me also, I had that problem at the middle of the project, so I limited browsers to chrome and ff. But when I'll have to really deploy, this could be an issue.

An application is limited to 10,000 uploaded files per version. Each file is limited to a maximum size of 32 megabytes. Additionally, if the total size of all files for all versions exceeds the initial free 1 gigabyte, then there will be a $0.13 per GB per month charge.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Deployments

The solution could be to deploy each language as an application, if your data is not related together between languages

Comment: Hm, deploying multiple applications might not be suitable. In terms of size, I am well under 1GB threshold. But number of files is a problem, and more importantly in the deferredJs folder. Wondering if there is some trick to keep this under control without loosing on cross browser compatibility or locale.

Comment: I started looking at the deployed folders to see where are the files. I don't seem to have 10000 files :-( (do you think the jars are unzipped?)
When you go to your war folder (after you compiled your GWT app) are there 34K files?

Comment: Actually no, there are around 16.5K files over there. But when you try to upload your app with appcfg, a temporary folder is created right before upload. The file count in that is around 34K. And that file count is what should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might also be deploying all of your gwt classes along with your application.

When I was a heavy appengine user, I was sure to jars all my uploaded classes (and not include any non-shared gwt code).  You might want to $ `find . -n "*.class" | wc -l` to count how many classes you are sending.

Jarring up your classes beforehand will make 15000 class files = 1 jar file.

It just sucks to make huge jars since you'll need to redeploy the whole jar on every change.  Better to have lots of small jars. ;)

Comment: Also check out using Soft Permutations.

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations

These allow you to use deferred binding, but collapse permutations and compile them together.  Unless your permutations have vastly different amounts of code, the little bit of extra file size per permutation versuses fewer permutations will likely help you.

Comment: Yes it sounds coherent: the classes for the server side (and shared) only should be included when deploying. This can be automated through a gradle script (or ant, maven)

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to put all the GWT generated files into a ZIP and serve them with a servlet.

To optimize things a bit I put every file in memcache after dezipping.